# Setup scheduled python skript on specific date or every day

Tags: python, schedule

I have a python script than can post a message on a board through an API. Running this manually works perfect.

Now I'd like to make a list of messages and e.g. post one every day. Or one for my wife/childrens on birthday etc.

I could setup a raspi to do that but i was wondering if there might be an easy way of doing this without having to run a computer all the time as this thing would do nothing most of the time. I can run this script in google colab for example but I don't think there is an option to schedule that. Also I don't want to pay a server for this toy. Is there something out there providing access to an python interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [python anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) and schedule the code to run every 24 hours, after some time they will stop running the code, but they will send you an email telling you so, and you can just start it again

Comment: Sounds perfect. I will give a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a cron job. You can run it from a self-hosted or online linux system. A windows PC might work too, but I think it's overkill as a task scheduler system.

There are services that abstract it for you, check out https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ they have a scheduled jobs feature to run a script daily or hourly.

Azure has a [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) feature that can run python scripts as well.

If you already have some VPS service running cPanel, you can check if the VPS has python installed and schedule jobs from the cPanel interface as well.

Another option are serverless cloud systems like [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-tutorial.html) or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) but I find them all much more complicated to setup.

A further option is to make use of CI/CD pipelines from hosted git sites like Gitlab, they have [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) that could run your script too.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy with Rocketry:

```
from rocketry import Rocketry
from rocketry.conds import daily

app = Rocketry()

@app.task(daily)
def do_daily():
    ... # This function runs once a day

@app.task(daily.between('13:00', '15:00'))
def do_daily_at_specific_time():
    ... # This function runs once a day at 1 PM to 3 PM

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

See more: https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/

Disclaimer, I'm the author.

Comment: with this solution my pc has to be on, right?

Comment: @nanquim Yes, but your PC must be on regardless of the solution. I also realized the answer pointed to the old version when it was named as Red Engine (fixed that).